# Sync iPhone calendar with custom calendar

Tags: ios, calendar, synchronization

i'm new iOS developer; and develop an birthday app so i need to create a calendar and take permission to access to iPhone calendar and sync all events on iPhone calendar to my new calendar inside my app;
i create DSLCalendar from this [link](https://github.com/PeteC/DSLCalendarView) but it have own calendar can i sync iPhone events with this calendar and send custom notifications

Comment: no; still waiting for any answers

Comment: thanks for the response.. If you find any solution, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I'm currently working on this.. As far as I understood the best way to sync your calendar with the device calendar is to create a new calendar `EKCalendar`, you can set the type to `EKCalendarTypeBirthday`, and sync the app with your new calendar..

[Check documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765) | 
[Check the example from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010160)

Comment: If you think this is the right answer for you, let me know, I will change it to answer, for you to accept.
I will be working on this.. Maybe can give more details later, right now i'm searching for answers.

Comment: Please explain more; for more clarification

Comment: you reached to any answer; or still searching

Comment: any help please; still searching for any answer but i didn't